# Load unmapped tables in Symfony with Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have tables in my database, that are not managed by Symfony; there are no entities for these tables. They are tables from another application, I import them and use Symfony to generate statistics from the data in the tables.

How do I access this?
Can i use doctrine and a regular repository for this?
I just want to read data, not update.

Right now I'm using straight mysqli_connect and mysqli_query, but that just doesn't feel right using Symfony 5.

Comment: Besides using straight SQL as described in the answer below, the Doctrine ORM also supports what it calls [Native SQL](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/native-sql.html#native-sql).  You will have to read through it carefully to see if any of the approaches fit your use case.  And of course you can always just define entities if you want.

Comment: Thanks, this seems a good way to do it indeed. Defining the entities would be a big work for a few table reads.

Comment: Don't overlook the possibility of defining SQL views to extract exactly what info you app uses.  And then map entities against the (presumably) simple views.  Many choices.

Answer (score 2):

You should just be able to query with sql. The following example comes straight from the docs:

```
// src/Repository/ProductRepository.php

// ...
class ProductRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function findAllGreaterThanPrice(int $price): array
    {
        $conn = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection();

        $sql = '
            SELECT * FROM product p
            WHERE p.price > :price
            ORDER BY p.price ASC
            ';
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute(['price' => $price]);

        // returns an array of arrays (i.e. a raw data set)
        return $stmt->fetchAllAssociative();
    }
}
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#querying-with-sql